# Subtitle for a section

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I'm using XeLaTeX to take notes in class, and I am using a new section for each lecture. Since the lectures have different teachers, I'd like a small italic subtitle for each `\section`.

I'm using the article class.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One problem with simply adding some formatted "teacher name" text after `\section` is that nothing prevents a page break immediately after the teacher name. (By default, LaTeX ensures that a section heading is followed by at least two lines of text.) Therefore I would use the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and its ability to execute additional code after the section title has been typeset (but still within `\section`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\sectionpostamble}{}
\newcommand*{\teacher}[1]{%
  \def\sectionpostamble{#1}%
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  [\normalfont\small\itshape\raggedleft\sectionpostamble
  \global\let\sectionpostamble\relax]

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\teacher{Donald~E. Knuth}
\section{foo}

\blindtext

\section{bar}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Comment: What would I have to change to make this work with subsections as well?

Comment: @InfiniteSquirrel: I believe just change `\titleformat{\section}` to `\titleformat{\subsection}`, then adjust the formatting in the three lines following to typeset the subsection how you like. For me, this involved changing `\Large` to `\large` and `\thesection` to `\thesubsection`, both in the first line following the `\titleformat` command.

Answer (score 11):

You can define such a command yourself. For example:

```
\newcommand\teacher[1]{\begin{flushright}\small\textit{#1}\end{flushright}}
```

This can be used as

```
\section{TeX}
\teacher{Prof.~Knuth}
```

Comment: Should be `\teacher{Prof.~Knuth}`, shouldn't it? To get the correct spacing I mean. (My German nature tells me to also add the `Dr.~`, while I'm not sure if the full title is necessary for class notes.)

Comment: @Martin: Well, I agree it's a good manner to use `~`. However, `~` does not modify the spacing, but only mean "nonbreak space". There's no different here (it's very short).

Comment: @Leo Liu: There is normally no change in spacing inside normal text if `~` is used, BUT TeX adds an extra wide space after the `.` because it thinks its the end of a sentence. Using a `~` or `\ ` fixes that. The `~` has the added benefit of being non-breakable as you pointed already out. I would therefore add a `\frenchspacing` in the `flushright` environment to directly disable the extra space after `.`.

Comment: @Martin: You are right. I forgot that.

Comment: Is there any way of eliminating the line spacing between the \section and the \teacher?

Comment: Yes, there's many ways to implement such a command. For example, use `\nobreak\hfill\textit{\small#1}\par`.

Comment: Is there a way to add a subtitle for a section to _only one section_?