# How can I get the capital letter T that looks like a J?

Tags: fonts, overleaf, letters

The letter that I want to obtain is:

[image]

Here the packages and style settings of my overleaf project:

```
% packages and related macros

\usepackage[final]{optional}% draft, etc

% Language and encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% from guit forum: http://www.guit.sssup.it/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=3287
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasitalian{\babel@savevariable\@clubpenalty
  \@clubpenalty3000 }
\makeatother

% Mathematics and related stuff

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


% Fonts and related stuff

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbats
\usepackage{marvosym} % for \Keyboard etc

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage[osf]{erewhon}% extension of Utopia, osf=old-style-figures
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% sans typewriter
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{cabin}% sans serif
\usepackage[utopia,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{textcomp}% AFTER newtxtext to avoid clashes
\usepackage{wasysym}
% font for Aspect Ratio by Claudio Beccari and Agostino De Marco
% the default variant is compatible with lmodern font
\usepackage[TM]{ar}

% Floating objects and related stuff
\usepackage{float}
% I got this somewhere on the net:
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.65}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.60}

\usepackage[above]{placeins}

%\usepackage{picins} % Warning, not included in TeXLive

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    %format=hang,%
    labelsep=space,%
    font=small,labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
    %justification=raggedright,%
    singlelinecheck=true%,%
    %width=1.1\textwidth%%
}
\captionsetup[table]{
    %format=hang,%
    labelsep=space,%
    font=small,labelfont={bf,sf,small},%bf,%
    justification=raggedright,%
    singlelinecheck=true,%
    %width=0.8\textwidth,%
    belowskip=0.5em%
}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
    %format=hang,%
    labelsep=space,%
    font=small,labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
    %justification=raggedright,%
    singlelinecheck=true%,%
    %width=1.1\textwidth%%
}

\captionsetup[ctable]{
    %format=hang,%
    labelsep=space,%
    font=small,labelfont={sf,bf,small},% bf
    %justification=raggedright,%
    singlelinecheck=true,%
    width=0.8\textwidth,%
    belowskip=0.5em%
}

\usepackage[innercaption,wide]{sidecap}

%% see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%% A new environment: dancingfigure
%% See original solution by Enrico Gregorio:
%% http://www.guit.sssup.it/phpbb/viewtopic.php?t=8077
%
\newcounter{dancingfigure}
\newenvironment{dancingfigure}[2][]
  {\refstepcounter{dancingfigure}%
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\label{DF@\arabic{dancingfigure}}}\temp
   \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{DF@\arabic{dancingfigure}}}}
     {\odddancingfigure}{\evendancingfigure}
   \begin{SCfigure}[#2][#1]}
  {\end{SCfigure}}
\newcommand{\odddancingfigure}{\def\positioning{r}}
\newcommand{\evendancingfigure}{\def\positioning{l}}
\newcommand{\dancinginclude}[5]{% all mandatory parameters
  \makebox[#1][\positioning]{%
    \raisebox{#5}{%
        \includegraphics[width=#2,#3]{#4}}}}
%
% % Example of usage:
%
%    \begin{dancingfigure}%
%        [t]% position on the page
%        {0.8}% sidecaption with, in terms of image length
%    \dancinginclude%
%        {0.7\textwidth}% box width
%        {0.8\textwidth}% image width (inside box)
%        {}% additional option in includegraphics
%        {chapter_2/images/ac_load_factor.pdf}
%        {2em}% raise the image of this amount
%    \caption{\finalhyphendemerits=1000
%                % {\bf debug: \positioning} ---
%                This is a Long caption. Volo in richiamata. Il valore del fattore
%                di carico normale è determinato prevalentemente dal rapporto fra la
%                portanza e il peso, se si trascura il contributo della spinta
%            }%
%    \label{fig:AC:Load:Factor}%
%    \end{dancingfigure}

% Graphics and related stuff

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[%
    dvipsnames, % svgnames
    ]%
    {xcolor}% before tikz

\definecolor{mydarkgreen}{rgb}{0.03,0.47,0.03}
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{rgb}{0.07,0.08,0.4}
\definecolor{mylightblue}{rgb}{.8, .8, 1}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{mydarkgray}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}
\definecolor{mylightyellow}{rgb}{0.97,0.91,0.81}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.4,.4,1}
\definecolor{colKeys}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{RGB}{28,172,0}
\definecolor{colString}{RGB}{170,55,241}

% Units of measure according to the SI standard

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  load=derived,
  unitsep=thin,
  valuesep=thin,
  decimalsymbol=comma,
  expproduct=cdot,
  % digitsep=thin,
  group-separator={},% ver. 2
  sepfour=false
}
\newunit{\inch}{in}
\newunit{\foot}{ft}
\newunit{\feet}{ft}
\newunit{\lb}{lb}
\newunit{\lbf}{lbf}
\newunit{\slug}{slug}
\newunit{\rankine}{\ensuremath{^\circ}R}
\newunit{\fahrenheit}{\ensuremath{^\circ}F}
\newunit{\kilopond}{kg\ensuremath{_\mathrm{f}}}
\newunit{\knots}{kts}

% Miscellaneous stuff

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

% smart cross-referencing
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
% Si veda "Breve guida ai pacchetti più usati" di Enrico Gregorio
% http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/breveguida.pdf
\makeatletter
\vref@addto\extrasitalian{\def\reftextfaraway#1{a pagina~\pageref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{nccmath}
%\usepackage{ctable}

% Table of contents per chapter

\usepackage[italian,tight]{minitoc}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addto\captionsitalian{\mtcselectlanguage{italian}}
}
%\mtcsetpagenumbers{secttoc}{off}
%\nostcpagenumbers

% Advanced header and footer management

\usepackage[
            %sf,
            %bf,
            %compact,
            %topmarks,
            %calcwidth,%
            pagestyles
            ]{titlesec}

\newcommand\mycoloredline[2]{%
    \hhline{%
    >{\arrayrulecolor{mylightblue}\doublerulesepcolor{myblue}}%
    |#1:=:#2|}%
}

%\renewpagestyle{empty}[\small\sffamily]{
\renewpagestyle{empty}[\small]{
  \sethead{}{}{}
  \setfoot{}{}{}
}

%\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small\sffamily]{
\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small]{
  \footrule
  \setfoot{}{\usepage}{}}

% needs \usepackage{calc} above
\widenhead*{0pt}{\marginparsep + \marginparwidth} % symmetrically
\renewpagestyle{plain}{}
\newpagestyle{mybook}[\bfseries\sffamily\footnotesize]{
    \headrule
    \sethead%
        [{\makebox[\marginparwidth+\marginparsep][l]{\thepage}{\chaptername}\ \thechapter\ \ {\sffamily\mdseries\chaptertitle}}][][]
        {}{}{\raggedleft\thesection\ \ {\sffamily\mdseries\sectiontitle}{\makebox[\marginparwidth+\marginparsep][r]{\thepage}}}
    % NB: il footer potrà essere vuoto nella versione definitiva !!
    \footrule
    \setfoot%
        [][][\color{mydarkblue}\sf\scriptsize \myFooterLeft]% A. De Marco, D. P. Coiro
        {\color{mydarkblue}\sf\scriptsize \myFooterRight}{}{}% Elementi di Dinamica e simulazione di volo
}
\pagestyle{mybook}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Advanced graphics package

\usepackage{tikz}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Setting for CHAPTER TITLE FORMAT

% http://web.slzm.de/blog/latex/schone-kapiteltitelseiten-in-latex/
%
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % style 2, 3, 4
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.shapes,shapes} % 3
% Style 4
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{%
%   \hfill \tikz[remember picture] \node[] (nr) {\fontsize{120}{70}\selectfont\color{blue!50!black}\textbf{\thechapter~}};% ~
  \hfill \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \rule{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep+2pt}{0pt}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \tikz[remember picture] \node[] (nr) {\fontsize{120}{70}\selectfont\color{blue!50!black}\textbf{\thechapter~}};% ~
    }%
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \coordinate (leftborder) at ($(nr)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (leftborderhigh) at ($(nr.north west)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (leftborderlow) at ($(nr.south west)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (left) at ($(nr.west)+(-1.5,0)$);
    \fill[blue!20!white] (leftborderhigh) -- ($(nr.north west)+(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!20!white] (leftborderlow) -- ($(nr.south west)-(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue!50!black,line width=0.1em,line join=round] (left) -- ($(nr.south west)+(0,-0.5)$) -- ($(nr.south east)+(0,-0.5)$) -- ($(nr.north east)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.north west)+(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder);
    %
    %\node [red,right] at ($(nr)-(0.93\textwidth,-20pt)$) {\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont\color{blue!50!black}\textbf{\chaptername}};
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2.2cm}{24.6cm}}
    \pgftext[left,base]{\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont\color{blue!50!black}\textbf{\chaptername}}
    %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{-2ex}
{\filleft\fontsize{28}{32}\selectfont\vskip\baselineskip}% \fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont\scshape
[\vspace{0ex}]
%
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/subtitle-for-a-section
%
\newcommand*{\mySectionPostamble}{}
\newcommand*{\mySectionComment}[1]{%
  \def\mySectionPostamble{#1}%
}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  [\normalfont\small\raggedleft\mySectionPostamble
  \global\let\mySectionPostamble\relax]


\usepackage{ctable}% must be loaded after tikz

% Document layout and related stuff

\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspace
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
%\setstretch{1.0}
\def\mynormalstretch{1.1}% 1.15
\setstretch{\mynormalstretch}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}% as of 2009
\usepackage{fullwidth}

\usepackage{mparhack} % marginpar hack, for two-side docs

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% page layout with geometry
\usepackage[%
            % chose this for a4
            a4paper,textwidth=15.5cm,textheight=26.0cm,%
            %
            inner=2.3cm,% 1.5cm,% 1cm,%
            %hcentering,%
            vcentering,%
            marginparwidth=2.2cm,% 2.8cm%,% 2.2cm,%
            %showframe%
            ]{geometry}

% Listings and related stuff

\usepackage[hyper]{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listato}
\newcommand{\lstInCaption}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize]|#1|}

% MATLAB as default
\lstset{%
    float=hbp,%
    language=Matlab,%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,%
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},%
    stringstyle=\color{colString},%
    commentstyle=\color{colComments},%
    columns=[l]fixed,% flexible,%
    keepspaces=true,%
    %tabsize=2,%
    frame=lines,% single,%
    extendedchars=true,%
    showspaces=false,%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    numbers=none,% left,%
    numberstyle=\tiny,%
    breaklines=true,%
    %lineskip=-2pt,%
    backgroundcolor=\color{myblue}, %
    breakautoindent=true,%
    numberbychapter=true,%
    captionpos=t,%
    belowcaptionskip=0.2\baselineskip%\medskipamount%
}
\lstset{%
   morekeywords={cell,interp3,interpn,fnplt,fneval%
      ,odeset,ode113,ode15s,ode23s,ode23t,ode23tb,cell2mat,%
      convvel,convang,convforce,convlength,deg2rad,atmoscoesa,atmosisa,atmosnonstd,%
      datcomimport,importdata,fieldnames,assignin%
      ,fnval,csaps,fmincon%
      ,classdef,properties,methods%
   }
}
\lstset{%
   emph={myfun,myfunction2x1,f_prandtl_a_b,%
      DSVAircraft,myAC,costLongEquilibriumStaticStickFixed,myNonLinearConstraint,dummyNonLinearConstraint,%
      eqLongDynamicStickFixed,calc_CD0_k_Tmax,MassStickFree,cla,eps,},%
   emphstyle={%
      \color{red!80!black}%
         \ttfamily\bfseries%
   }
}

\lstset{%
    emph=[1]{interp1,pi,norm,sin,cos,disp,ode45,cd,set,get,gca,gradient,length,tan,gamma,sqrt,diag,acos,atan,asin,imag,real,subplot,sound,zeros,interp2,meshgrid,input,sprintf,xlabel,ylabel,plot,print, legend,grid,figure,hold},emphstyle=[1]\color{black}, %some words to emphasise
}


% DATCOM
\lstdefinelanguage{Datcom}{%
    emph={%
        \$FLTCON,\$OPTINS,\$SYNTHS,\$BODY,%
        \$WGPLNF,\$HTPLNF,\$VTPLNF,\$SYMFLP,\$ASYMFLP,%
        \$},%
    emphstyle={%
          \color{red!80!black}%
            \ttfamily\bfseries%
        },%
    morekeywords={%
        WT,\$,NMACH,MACH,NALT,ALT,NALPHA,ALSCHD,%
        SREF,CBARR,BLREF,%
        XCG,XW,ZW,ALIW,XH,ZH,ALIH,XV,ZV,VERTUP,%
        NX,X,R,%
        CHRDTP,SSPNE,SSPN,CHRDR,SAVSI,CHSTAT,%
        TWISTA,SSPNDD,DHDADI,DHDADO,TYPE,%
        NACA,%
        CASEID,%
        DAMP,DIM,DERIV,TRIM,PART,SAVE,NEXT,CASE%
        WT,LOOP,NMACH,MACH,VINF,NALPHA,ALSCHD,RNNUB,NALT,%
            ALT,PINF,TINF,HYPERS,STMACH,TSMACH,TR,GAMMA,%
        SREF,CBARR,BLREF,ROUGFC,XCG,ZCG,XW,ZW,ALIW,XH,ZH,ALIH,XV,XVF,ZV,ZVF,SCALE,%
        VERTUP,HINAX,NX,X,S,P,R,ZU,ZL,BNOSE,BTAIL,BLN,BLA,DS,%
        ITYPE,METHOD,CHRDR,CHRDBP,CHRDTP,SSPN,SSPNE,SSPNOP,SAVSI,SAVSO,CHSTAT,%
        TWISTA,SSPNDD,DHDADI,DHDADO,TYPE,TOVC,DELTAY,XOVC,CLI,ALPHAI,CLALPA,CLMAX,CMO,%
        LERI,LERO,CAMBER,TOVCO,XOVCO,CMOT,CLMAXL,CLAMO,TCEFF,KSHARP,SLOPE,ARCL,%
        XAC,DWASH,YCM,CLD,TYPEIN,NPTS,XCORD,YUPPER,YLOWER,MEAN,THICK,NGH,%
        GRDHT,FTYPE,NDELTA,DELTA,PHETE,PHETEP,CHRDFI,CHRDFO,SPANFI,SPANFO,%
        CPRMEI,CPRMEO,CAPINS,CAPOUT,DOSDEF,DOBCIN,DOBCOT,SCLD,SCMD,%
        CB,TC,NTYPE,JETFLP,CMU,DELJET,EFFJET,STYPE,NDELTA,DELTAL,DELTAR,%
        SPANFI,SPANFO,PHETE,CHRDFI,CHRDFO,DELTAD,DELTAS,XSOC,XSPRME,%
        HSOC,AIETLP,NENGSP,THSTCP,PHALOC,PHVLOC,PRPRAD,ENGFCT,%
        BWAPR3,BWAPR6,BWAPR9,NOPBPE,BAPR75,YP,CROT,%
        AIETLJ,AMBSTP,AMBTMP,JEALOC,JEANGL,JELLOC,JERAD,JESTMP,%
        JETOTP,JEVELO,JEVLOC,JIALOC,JINLTA,NENGSJ,THSTCJ%
    },
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinelanguage{DatcomOutput}{%
}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyInputForMatlab}{%
}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyNoSpecificLanguage}{%
    emph={},%
    emph={[2]},%
    emph={[3]},%
    emph={[4]}%
}

\lstloadlanguages{Matlab,Datcom,DatcomOutput,MyInputForMatlab,MyNoSpecificLanguage}

% see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18532/listing-language-for-screen-session
\lstnewenvironment{myCommandLine}
    {\lstset{%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray},% \color{hellgelb}, %
        frame=none,%
        columns=[l]fixed,%flexible, %
        prebreak=\makebox[1.4ex][r]{\color{blue}\raisebox{-0.9ex}[0ex][0ex]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}},
        keepspaces=true,%
        escapechar=~,% use this for output
        morekeywords={ls,pwd,cp,mv},
        identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
        keywordstyle=\color{red!60!black}\bfseries,% \color{colKeys},%\fontseries{b}\selectfont, %
        stringstyle=\color{colString}, %
        literate={\$}{{\textcolor{blue}{\$}}}1}% prompt symbol
    }
    {}
\lstnewenvironment{myCommandLineOutput}
    {\lstset{%
        language=MyNoSpecificLanguage,%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,%
        backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray},% \color{hellgelb}, %
        lineskip=-1pt,%
        frame=none,%
        columns=[l]fixed,%flexible, %
        prebreak=\makebox[1.4ex][r]{\color{blue}\raisebox{-0.9ex}[0ex][0ex]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}},
        keepspaces=true,%
        escapechar=~% use this for output
        }
    }
    {}
\lstnewenvironment{myCommandLineOutputSmaller}
    {\lstset{%
        language=MyNoSpecificLanguage,%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
        backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray},% \color{hellgelb}, %
        lineskip=-1pt,%
        frame=none,%
        columns=[l]fixed,%flexible, %
        prebreak=\makebox[1.4ex][r]{\color{blue}\raisebox{-0.9ex}[0ex][0ex]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}},
        keepspaces=true,%
        escapechar=~% use this for output
        }
    }
    {}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% after listings package to avoid clash

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric-comp,
    doi=false,url=true,isbn=false,
    hyperref=true,
    sorting=none,
    natbib=true]{biblatex}
    
\bibliography{book_bibliography}
%% EOF
```

Comment: Hi, please where you have taken your image?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html, especially https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/qtlinostroke/.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner :-) For my humble opinion it is the T of mtpro2 :-) https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html. See the image, please (Script, Fraktur, "Holey-Roman-Bold", and Blackboard bold fonts). The B it is a Times.

Comment: Thanks Dr.ManuelKuehner and @Sebastiano for your answers. But I cannot make work the mtpro2lite in my overleaf project. Can you help me? P.s. I am using a template prepared by my professor. I've added the packages and style (used in my overleaf project) to my first question in this section. Sorry for the length of the code.

Comment: P.s. The image in the question is taken from course notes.

Comment: @Giuseppe Good morning from the Sicily. Do you know mtpro2[lite]?

Comment: Good morning @Sebastiano. No, I'm a beginner of LaTex world.

Comment: You must to find an alternative symbol for the \mathcal{T} because mtpro2 it is not a free font. Just only  mtpro2[lite] option is free but it is missing for your T. You should switch with another font (but you have many declared packages - it is possible to have a conflict with the fonts). An alternative it is to create a image of the T and fit it like a character.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I think I will settle for $\mathcal{T}_{B}$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has accepted a suggestion made in the comments.